# Why Deployer say storage:link failed when i start using public disk in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, symlink, php-deployer

i use php deployer tool (Deployer.org) for deploy my app on Laravel 5.5.

When i start use public disk with symlynk storage -> storage/app/public,
 i have got error on deployng:

```
In Client.php line 96:

The command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/releases/1/artisan 
storage:link" failed

Exit Code: 1 (General error)

Host Name: production

================

In Filesystem.php line 228:

symlink(): No such file or directory
```

I saw in  directy on host /releases/1/public broken symlink to my local MacOs folder storage -> /Users/user1/Code/project/storage/app/public

I repeat new installation from scratch Laravel project&Deployer but still gor error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I accidentally pushed up the
Public/Storage folder to git. (

Comment: What does that mean?